# Multiple record combine into one using object manipulation

Tags: jquery

I have an array of the object which is as follows:

```
[
    {
      user_id: 1,
      first_name: 'Test 1',
      last_name: 'Test 1',
      milestone_id: 21,
      milestone_description: 'Milestone 1'
    },
    {
      user_id: 1,
      first_name: 'Test 1',
      last_name: 'Test 1',
      milestone_id: 22,
      milestone_description: 'Milestone 2'
    },
    {
      user_id: 2,
      first_name: 'Test 2',
      last_name: 'Test 2',
      milestone_id: 23,
      milestone_description: 'Milestone 1'
    },
    {
      user_id: 2,
      first_name: 'Test 2',
      last_name: 'Test 2',
      milestone_id: 24,
      milestone_description: 'Milestone 2'
    },
    {
      user_id: 3,
      first_name: 'Test 3',
      last_name: 'Test 3',
      milestone_id: null,
      milestone_description: null
    }
]
```

Here I have some users who have multiple milestones associated and some user has no milestone. I want to combine milestones into sub-array if there is any milestone associated.

[image]

Please suggest to me how could I do that with jquery loop.

Tried this:

```
let finalArr = []
getDetails.rows.forEach(element => {
    element[element.in_user_id] = [
        {
            'milestone_id': element.milestone_id,
            'milestone_description': element.milestone_description
        }
    ]
    finalArr[element.in_user_id] = element
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are looking for a solution using jQuery OR Node.js. There are completely different environments required to run jQuery code and Node.js code. Besides, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to do this for jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for your merging process

```
let finalArr = [];
getDetails.rows.forEach(element => {
    if(finalArr[element.user_id]==undefined){
            finalArr[element.user_id]={
                user_id: element.user_id,
                first_name: element.first_name,
                last_name: element.last_name,
                milestones:[]
            }
    }
    if(element.milestone_id !=null){
        finalArr[element.user_id].milestones.push({
        milestone_id: element.milestone_id,
        milestone_description: element.milestone_description
      })
    }
});
```

I hope this will work for you.